# Relative efficiency of String.trim() vs checking for whitespace

Tags: javascript, string, webkit

I'm a predominantly-C developer working on a project that requires some JavaScript on an embedded device. I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to handle using `String.trim()` to strip spaces off of the end of a string, in a context where the spaces are an uncommon edge case.

My question is whether it be more efficient to wrap the `String.trim()` call with a check like this:

```
if (text.charCodeAt(text.length - 1) === 0x20) {
    text = text.trim();
}
```

or just let `text.trim()` handle the check. Assume trailing spaces will occur in roughly 1/100 entries, and that there are no problems other than efficiency with calling trim on every entry. My guess is that `String.trim()` would be implemented in native code, so the check there should be at least as efficient as the calls to `String.charCodeAt()` and `text.length`.  This is for a Webkit or Webkit-based browser.

Thanks for indulging my noobishness.

Comment: Another question is: given the text ends with whitespace, how much whitespace at the end?

Comment: Furthermore I'm wondering it will make a significant difference. You better try to *profile* your program and speedup the method calls that take a significant amount of time.

Comment: Typically one space, but we need to account for multiple.

Comment: Furthermore mind that [`trim`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) removes whitespace both at the front and at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the WebKit source, and it does seem that a call to `String.charCodeAt()` would have a similar execution time as a call to `String.trim()` that doesn't result in any actual trimming.  I also discovered `String.trimRight()` which would save one check since I only care about trailing spaces.  And since `String.trimRight()` handles everything in a native-cpp context I think it's safe to assume that bouncing back out to JavaScript context is going to be less efficient.